# sql where contains

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, contains

```
TABLE A
|column1|column2| 

TABLE B
|column1|column2|
```

SQL QUERY

```
SLECT a.column1
b.column
FROM A a, B b
Where Contains(a.column1, b.column1)
```

But, it has syntax error near b.column in Contains.

Comment: -1 Play around in the TSQL command-line client or SSMS. Break down the query into parts and/or check out the reference manual and/or read the error message closely. These sort of things are far too localized and need to be resolved locally.

Answer (score 5):

You missed a comma?

```
SELECT a.column1, b.column1
FROM A a, B b
Where Contains(a.column1, b.column1)
```

Comment: it's my mistake on my question.  My real query is SELECT a.column1, ,b.column1 FROM A a, B b Where Contains(a.column1, b.column1)

Comment: If this is your real query, then you've got a comma to much between a.column1 and b.column1 in your select part

Comment: Sorry, my duplicate mistake  SELECT a.column1, b.column1 FROM A a, B b Where Contains(a.column1, b.column1)

Comment: SELECT a.column1, b.column1 FROM A a, B b Where Contains(a.column1, b.column1) also has a error

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot specify column name into the search condition.

`CONTAINS` can search for:

- A word or phrase.
- The prefix of a word or phrase.
- A word near another word.
- A word inflectionally generated from another (for example, the word drive is the inflectional stem of drives, drove, driving, and
  driven).
- A word that is a synonym of another word using a thesaurus (for example, the word "metal" can have synonyms such as "aluminum" and "steel").

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx